# Finding a function to fit a curve

Tags: curves

I have coordinates of four points on a curve and want to find a function that will draw the curve.

The points are [0,0] [120,280] [240,2800] [360,28000]

It looks like an exponential curve in that 120 is 1/3 of 360 and 280 is 2.8 * 100, 240 is 2/3 of 360 and 2800 is 2.8 * 1000, 360 is 3/3 of 360 and 28000 is 2.8 * 10000

It looks like it should be a simple function. I tried the function finder on ZunZun but it produced hideously complicated functions that didn't output exact results.

Answer (score 1):

The point $(0,0)$ is ruining your exponential.  The other points fit $y=28\cdot 10^{x/120}$ perfectly.  If the first point were $(0,28)$ it would fit as well.  If you got your data off a graph, can you tell the difference between the two points?

Comment: Fantastic Ross. Thank you. I still have some figuring out since I would like to get y = close to 0 when x is 0 but I guess that can't be so with this curve.

Comment: On the scale of your data $28$ is close to $0$.

Comment: True. Thanks again Ross.

Comment: I really can't say that without knowing about the source of the data.  You may have some good reason to know that the curve should go through $(0,0)$.  If the points are exact, I don't think you will get a nice fit.  You could use $y=28\cdot (10^{x/120}-1)$, which misses all the others by $28$.  Maybe that is more acceptable.

Comment: That's very helpful, Ross, thank you. Can I bias the curve so that it would also pass through (30,28) and as close as possible to (0,0)?

Comment: If it helps I am using it to represent a life mapped around a circle where the first 120 degrees represents conception to birth, the next 120 degrees represents birth to 7.7 years and the final 120 degrees represents from 7.7 years to 77.7 years. The scale around the circle should give the age in days according to that exponential distribution. The 1st 120 degrees represents 280 days, by 7.7 years the age is approx 2800 days, by 77.7 years we reach approx 28000 days.

Comment: The original curve goes through $(30,49.79)$ so with the subtraction of $28$ you are quite close.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I subtracted 28*(120-x)/119 where x < 120 and that achieved what I was looking for.